# How to turn WiFi on\off based on location

Tags: iphone, wifi, geolocation

Applications such as [WiFi Matic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cprados.wificellmanager) on Android allow you to turn on\off your WiFi automatically depending on location. Even though this disables assisted GPS which uses WiFi to help the GPS lock, it's still a nice battery saver trick which I loved while in the Android world.

I couldn't find any iPhone app that does the same. Does it exist?
If not, is it because apple restricts such app control?

Comment: I haven't run any tests, but I can guarantee you that constantly polling GPS for location data to toggle the WiFi status will use considerably more energy than just polling for WiFi networks directly.

Comment: Would running IFFFT to run the location then notify you work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no public [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) to control the Wifi on iOS. Therefore Apple won't allow it on the AppStore.

If such an app exists then maybe on Cydia.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was asked 6 years back but I thought I should comment. With the latest IOS 14 update and the new Shortcut app. you can create an automation based on location. For example, when I leave X do the following action like turn WiFi Off. I have done this but did not get the opportunity to try it out due to the current restrictions on travel pandemic related and being a person with a disability I don't want to risk my behind.

My thoughts are till you are in that WiFi network and leave it; it should disable WiFi but I have also created an automation to turn WiFi On once I come back to that location. My dilemma is WiFi is turned off and I don't use Data much unless critical e.g. booking a Uber ride so when I arrive at my location, Data is switched off. Will my phone know where I am with this disabled; if not I think it will fail in connecting to WiFi when I have reached the location. The second automation of turning WiFi On would not work I guess

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist without jailbreak, (and if it does) checking (and saving!) your location each time waste alot of battery resulting in the opposite of what you're trying to achieve.

Besides, on iOS 7 if you open **Control Center** (by moving your finger from the bottom of the screen to the middle), you can **uncheck** WiFi very easily.
[image]

Comment: A) Google Now checks location regularly anyway B) WiFi Matic uses cell tower ID comparison instead of GPS so it doesn't waist battery

Comment: If you keep WiFi active on iOS, it will still try to find available WiFi networks, resulting in Battery drain/waste.

Comment: no it does not, that can occur only if WiFi is on and WiFi Matic keeps it off unless relevant cell towers are recognized. As long as your phone is not in aireplane mode it listens to cellular tower broadcasts periodically

Comment: Besides, when I get home I: 1) turn on WiFi 2) turn off BT 3) disable cell data transfer 4) switch to 2G as the reception in my home is really bad - so this was just a warm-up question

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous downvote without clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Another, semi-manual solution is to create a reminder for when you leave / arrive at a particular location to enable/disable your Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

Siri: "Turn Wifi OFF"

Siri: "Turn Wifi ON"

As Siri requires a data connection, turning WiFi on will only work if you have a cellular connection.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, only a jailbroken phone allows this capability.

As a workaround:

Use IFTTT and use the iOS location channel. Use Launch Center Pro to open the URL `prefs:root=WIFI`.

This will open the WiFi settings preference page.

Also have a look at [this overview of iOS Settings URLs](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/11/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-to-wifi-settings-airplane-mode-and-more-no-jailbreak-required/)

Answer (score 0):

I use recipes from IFTTT.com and get notifications to remind me what to do, based on my location.

A lot of restrictions on iOS, compared to android, but a location based notification is better than a reminder.

If entered  location, turn off WiFi.
If left  location, turn on WiFi.

I don't need to turn off, other times, so, YMMV here on the recipes.

You need to install "IF" app from the AppStore.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is, after all, one of a set of workarouds.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch off “Ask to Join Networks” your WiFi won’t chew up as much battery. That being said, the WiFi on iPhones doesn’t use a significant amount of power anyway.